# what is the meaning of this (redundant?) python expression?

Tags: python, testing, logic, expression

```
str='test'
example={'test':'value',}
return str in example and example[str] or None
```

why the seemingly redundant extra test for key `str` in `example`?

Comment: In English and recent Python you would write `return example[str] if str in example else None`

Comment: @JochenRitzel - This is again missing the point I was making in my answer. Based on his example it needs to catch the values that truth test to False

Comment: @jdi: most of the time when I see `or` used to return one of two values, the intent isn't really to prevent 0, '', [], etc from being returned, it's just a 'clever' one-liner for defaulting, because people are afraid their keyboards will wear out if they have to type a whole `if` block/expression. Personally I think it's a bit of an anti-pattern; in this case I would guess that the fact that you can't distinguish a "falsey" value stored under a key from a key that's not stored is more likely to be an unconsidered corner case (i.e. a bug), rather than desired behaviour.

Comment: Im not in any way defending the actual code the OP posted. I'm only trying to respond to what he is asking about this code. Its not a question of his intent, but rather the exact snippet he is asking to expand upon. In this snippet, it does filter out values that eval to False. If his question were "Is there a better way to achieve this x or y result?", then there would be a different stream of answerings offering alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this specific example, the check is to first make sure that 'test' is actually a valid key in the example dict, otherwise you would get a KeyError exception. Then the logic proceeds to check  the key and either return it, or a None if the value of example[str] evals to False

It would be a lot easier if this example simply did:

```
str='test'
example={'test':'value',}
return example.get(str, None) or None
```

**Update**

Even simpler, since the extra param to get() is not needed:

```
return example.get(str) or None
```

**Update 2**: Breaking down the truth tests and boolean operations from the OP (based on comments)

```
example = {
    'test' : 'value', 
    'test2': 0, 
    'test3': [],
}
test = lambda k: k in example and example[k] or None
print test('test')
# value
print test('test2')
# None
print test('test3')
# None
```

Comment: it would be even more easier if you just did `return example.get(str, None)`

Comment: @julio.alegria - That is incorrect. Simply returning that would allow an empty string, or a int 0, or any null type to be returned. The OPs example showed that it would return None if the value evaluated False.

Comment: I suggest you [reading more](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) about the `get()` method. If the key you pass is not found, `None` (not `False`) is returned or the default value (the second parameter). So actually, **even** easier (with the same result) would be doing `return example.get(str)`.

Comment: @julio.alegria - Again, you are wrong. And you should probably do that reading yourself. `d.get('test')` would return 0 if the value were 0. If you really wanted to simplify my example even further you could have suggested `d.get('test') or None`

Comment: and where does the user said that it shouldn't return 0?

Comment: I think you should read how boolean operations work in python: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations . Its not retuning True or False. its returning values. The fact that his expression does a truth test on the value prevents a zero or empty string or empty list, etc from being returned. Thus, his example will not let a 0 be returned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7178/discussion-between-jdi-and-julio-alegria)

Comment: @jdi is right.  but someone should mention that these boolean overloading things are slippery and bug-prone.  the clearer way is to use conditional one-liners, of the form `return x if some_condition else y`.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, the behaviour is different for the case where you're looking up a non-existent key (the extra test would prevent a `KeyError` exception being thrown).

However, it goes further than that because `example[str]` can be false in a boolean context.  e.g., it could be an empty string.

```
>>> str='test'
>>> example={'test':[],}
>>> str in example and example[str] or None
>>> str in example or None
True
```

So it is not quite redundant.  `str in example` checks for the existence of the key, whereas `and example[str]` is also checking the truthiness of the value.

Comment: Of course, if that is in fact the exact code the issue is more likely a copy/paste operation.

Answer (score 2):

Since Python evaluates Booleans lazily, you can safely omit parentheses in simple tests.  This might make it easier to read:

```
(str in example and example[str]) or None
```

In plain English:

"Make sure the dictionary `example` has the key `str` and that the key also has a non-False value. If so, return the value of the key `example[str]`. Otherwise return `None`"

Answer (score 0):

`str in example` is a boolean test to see if `str` is a key in `example`, while `example[str]` yields the actual value associated with that key.

Answer (score 0):

Graceful failure. If the key doesn't exist, the lookup 'example[str]' will fail at runtime. You'll get a fault, terminate your app and get a traceback. By checking for the key first you get the None value back instead and your application will go on on its merry way.

Another, more general approach would be to catch the exception and return None as a result of that.

```
def testfun():
    str='test2'
    example={'test':'value',}
    try:
        return example[str]
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

Comment: This doesn't offer the same protection of checking that the existing value does't eval to None

Comment: How do you mean? In what situation would the output differ?

Comment: If `example['test'] == 0` then it will end up returning 0 and not None. The OPs example checks also whether the value evaluates to False. Yours does not.

Answer (score 0):

If the key doesn't exist it will get `KeyError exception`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

str='test'
example={'test':'value',}

if str in example and example[str]:
    print example[str]
else:
    print False
```